# Interesting mdx bug?

Tags: mdx, olap, pyramid-analytics

If I run this:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
      Hierarchize
      ( EXISTING
        {
          [Product].[Product Categories].[Product].&[483]
         ,[Product].[Product Categories].[Product].&[486]
         ,[Product].[Product Categories].[Product].&[478]
         ,[Product].[Product Categories].[Product].&[479]
         ,[Product].[Product Categories].[Product].&[477]
         ,[Product].[Product Categories].[Product].&[484]
         ,[Product].[Product Categories].[Product].&[485]
         ,[Product].[Product Categories].[Product].&[317]
         ,[Product].[Product Categories].[Product].&[316]
         ,[Product].[Product Categories].[Product].&[583]
         ,[Product].[Product Categories].[Product].&[311]
         ,[Product].[Product Categories].[Product].&[594]
        }
      )
    } ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE 
  [Product].[Product Model Lines].[Product Line].&[M];
```

I get this:
[image]

Whereas if we comment out the `EXISTING` keyword:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
      Hierarchize
      ( --EXISTING
        {
          [Product].[Product Categories].[Product].&[483]
         ,[Product].[Product Categories].[Product].&[486]
         ,[Product].[Product Categories].[Product].&[478]
         ,[Product].[Product Categories].[Product].&[479]
         ,[Product].[Product Categories].[Product].&[477]
         ,[Product].[Product Categories].[Product].&[484]
         ,[Product].[Product Categories].[Product].&[485]
         ,[Product].[Product Categories].[Product].&[317]
         ,[Product].[Product Categories].[Product].&[316]
         ,[Product].[Product Categories].[Product].&[583]
         ,[Product].[Product Categories].[Product].&[311]
         ,[Product].[Product Categories].[Product].&[594]
        }
      )
    } ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE 
  [Product].[Product Model Lines].[Product Line].&[M];
```

We get the following:

[image]

We use Pyramid front-end. It would have been hoped that the guys there would have included the `EXISTING` keyword in their mdx rendering engine so that users did not have to worry about this bug.

Is it definitely a bug?

Does including `EXISTING` mean that scripts run slower?

Comment: Not sure what the issue could be. I ran the query without the Hierarchize - it ran fine. Ran with the construct(including Hierarchize) in a named set. It ran fine. Issue it seems is with how `Hierarchize` and `EXISTING` work together.

Comment: @SouravA - exactly - it is a bug in `Hierarchize`. I've emailed someone who speaks with the developers at MS and he is waiting for a response.

Comment: While you do that, I would suggest you open a connect item with MS so that the greater public is aware of the issue(and resolution hopefully)

Comment: I would be really interested in knowing what's going behind the scene that forces the result to be filtered off.

Comment: the bug only happens when you use hierarchize and also have a different hierarchy, from the same dimension, in the WHERE clasue

Comment: No I meant, what happens at the engine level which causes results to be wrong. That might be the key to deep dive into MDX and how it organizes data. Probably the MS guy can help.

Comment: Well the MS guy is apparently one of the analysis services dev team ....so it'll be a worry if he doesn't understand what is going on! More interesting is if it can be fixed and when can it be fixed - it is causing us problems

Comment: Can't you avoid the Hierarchize or use a named set? As a workaround..?

Comment: @SouravA the code is autogenerated by our tool Pyramid

Comment: Did you hear back from MS on this interesting bug?

Comment: I think I need to open a issue call in connection with this. Pyramid have implemented the use of `EXISTING` in the code generated by their client so for us it isn't a bit problem.